# Power cable for DVD Player too short

Tags: mounting, wire

I recently wall mounted my TV and put a shelf underneath for my dvd player. Unfortunately the power cable for the dvd player is too short. I've searched and searched for dvd players that have either a long cable or a cable that can be removed so I can buy a longer one.

I know I could buy an extension lead but it would look really ugly?

I cable needs to be 2m long, do currently about a metre short.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: An electrically competent friend could open the dvd and put in a longer cable... A simple task.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the existing cord is removable, you'll have to extend it with a second cord. Yes, the connection between the two will be ugly if it's hanging in the middle of the wall, but you could wrap up the whole first cable behind the player so that the joint between the two is also behind the player. You'll need a longer extension, but if it's important to you then it'll be worth it.

Comment: Yes, that's it, use a 2m extension cord so there's no lumpy plug in view.

Comment: If you cut the existing plug off the cord you can extend with a more compact connector such as (UK site - not sure if USA has similar) https://www.tlc-direct.co.uk/Products/BG458.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have a power cable that uses a standard barrel type connector, you should be able to find an extension cable to match the specifications. There is some variation in barrel connectors. The manual for your device may provide details, or a search of the 'net will provide that information. Had you included the model of the player, other options would be available.

Most extension cables of this sort will resemble the connector itself, in that there is minimal material surrounding the connector. When assembled/joined as the extension, there will be a small bulge in the line, but not particularly unsightly.

[image: barrel cable extension]

Picture not actual size!

Comment: This is assuming that the 'power' connection is a plug-in unit, and a low voltage supply. This sort of cable us not suitable for 240/110V use...

Comment: That's certainly valid and I had slightly overlooked the concept that this is a residential type of installation and not necessarily a (usually) smaller unit.